Windows NLB - configuring multiple sites on 443 port (SSL) with hostnames
I got two windows server (2016): Server A and Server B.
On each server are configured several IIS sites on port 443, with different hostname.
Server A:

hostname: app1.local (https on port 443)
hostname: anotherapp1.local (https on port 443)

Server B:

hostname: app2.local (https on port 443) (mirror of app1.local)
hostname: anotherapp2.local (https on port 443) (mirror of anotherapp1.local)

I would like to configurare NLB - Network Load Balancing to make a load balance between Server A and Server B.
My idea is to have a unique app.local to automatically distribute load between app1.local and app2.local, and same with anotherapp.local to distribute load between anotherapp1.local and anotherapp2.local.
Any idea on how to configure this using only Windows Server Network Load Balancer?

I think you need to learn about building a web farm and configuring load balancing using IIS server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/overview-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers
